# Firebase - Redirect From Domain A to Domain B

Tags: firebase, url, redirect, hosting, firebase-hosting

Firebase gave **.web.app** domains for free, so I currently have two domains for my Firebase website:

1. mywebsite.firebaseapp.com (Domain **A**).
2. mywebsite.web.app (Domain **B**).

I want to redirect all traffic from domain **A** to domain **B** with `firebase.json`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this...

```
hosting": {

  "redirects": [ {
    "source": "mywebsite.firebaseapp.com",
    "destination": "mywebsite.web.app",
    "type": 301
  }

}
```

Although if that doesn't work then there is probably no way to do this as both domains point to the same IP address and as far as I know, the firebase hosting DNS is not customizable.

Comment: It doesn't work, I guess this means that there is no way to do it :(

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. Sorry.